# Computer algebra tools for finding real dimension of an algebraic variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, computational-geometry, computer-algebra, real-algebraic-geometry, semialgebraic-geometry

I have a system of polynomial equations with the unknowns being real numbers. The set of solutions is infinite. What software can I use to compute the real dimension of the solution set?

The CAD-based approach, which is implemented in various computer algebra systems, is too slow for my problems.
I found several recent papers on other algorithms for finding the dimension but they were not accompanied with an open-source implementation.

I am looking for the implementation of some (preferably) non-randomized and exact method for computing the exact value of the dimension.

Comment: What are the typical degrees, # of variables and # of equations you are studying?

Comment: @AlonAmit  The simplest problem includes about 30 equations, 30 variables with solution dimension around 15.
But I would like to approach say 70 eqs. with 80 vars. and dim. 40.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_of_an_algebraic_variety), an abstract algorithm to compute the complex dimension of a variety is implemented at least in Maple and Macaulay2. You may need to consult the documentation for details.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine I am interested in computing not complex but *real* dimension. If I am not mistaken, Maple has only the CAD method implemented for computing the real dimension.